# How can I find the impulse responce of this ODE?

Tags: matlab, impulse-response

$$ \frac{^2()}{^2} + 2\frac{()}{}+ 1 = 2̈()$$

a. Write Matlab source code evaluate the impulse response of the system.
b. Write Matlab source code to evaluate and plot magnitude and phase the spectrum of
the impulse response of the system

Comment: Welcome to our stack exchange. Unfortunately complete homework questions are off topic here. Please show your own work so far and describe where you are stuck

Comment: “Impulse response” of a system is the output of the system when you put an impulse (Dirac delta function) in. So set x = delta, then solve for y, this will be your impulse response.